# How do I make labels on a node smaller (pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to make the nodes in the graph (below) have smaller labels (i.e smaller font) because currently my graph, when compiled, makes all the nodes collide with each other. How do I do this?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=both,
                  xmin=-1, xmax=2,ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                  axis lines=middle,
                  enlargelimits]
            \addplot[black] (2,0) node[above] {$dx$};
            \addplot[black] (0,2.2) node[below right] {$df$};
            \addplot[blue,samples=1000,domain=0:15] {0.7-0.7*x^2-0.5*sin(180*10*x/pi)};
            \node[label={135:{(0.0,0)}}, circle, fill, inner sep = 1pt] at (axis cs:0.0,0) {};
            \node[label={135:{(0.285,0)}}, circle, fill, inner sep = 1pt] at (axis cs:0.285,0) {};
            \node[label={135:{(0.66,0)}}, circle, fill, inner sep = 1pt] at (axis cs:0.66,0) {};
            \node[label={135:{(0.934,0)}}, circle, fill, inner sep = 1pt] at (axis cs:0.934,0) {};
            \node[label={45:{(1.218,0)}}, circle, fill, inner sep = 1pt] at (axis cs:1.218,0) {};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{The graph of equation \ref{fig:eqN}, $\frac{df}{dx}= r - rx^2 -\frac{1}{2}\sin{nx}\mbox{, for }r = 0.7, n = 10$}
        \label{fig:logistic8}
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make coordinates text so small that they will not overlap. As solution can be beside reducing their font size also rotate it:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style = {font=\tiny, inner sep=2pt, rotate=30, anchor=west},
        dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep = 1pt}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    xlabel=$dx$,
    ylabel=$df$,
    xmin=-1, xmax=2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
    enlargelimits]
    \addplot[blue,samples=1000,domain=0:15] {0.7-0.7*x^2-0.5*sin(180*10*x/pi)};
    \node[label=135:{(0.0,0)}, dot] at (0.0,0) {};
    \node[label=135:{(0.285,0)}, dot] at (0.285,0) {};
    \node[label=135:{(0.66,0)}, dot] at (0.66,0) {};
    \node[label=135:{(0.934,0)}, dot] at (0.934,0) {};
    \node[label=135:{(1.218,0)}, dot] at (1.218,0) {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]